# Customer Community User Activity (Event) Access

Tags: permissions, community

I am trying to expose Events in a read only manner to users with a Customer Community license.

Eventually I found out about the field `IsVisibleInSelfService`.  This field is not visible to System Administrators by default, but once you enable the FLS for it, you can set it to true and indeed the events become visible to the community user.

Is setting this field to true a proper way of exposing visibility of events to community users?  A colleague linked me to [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_customerportal.htm&language=en_US) which seems to suggest the user shouldnt get access to this data at all.

Furthermore, it seems awkward for me to be writing a trigger to ensure this field is checked for all new events -- I would expect there would be a checkbox somewhere which controlled this.  Does such a setting exist in salesforce?

Answer (score 3):

The link at [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) is the page you really want to be looking at for the answer to your question with respect to which objects are available to Communities users. `IsVisibleInSelfService` is something that typically would be applied to fields at the object level and then have it's actual visibility to particular users controlled through roles and user profiles. Its not something one would normally do on an Event by Event basis using a trigger!

This particular situation is where the use of record types would be especially appropriate. In essence, only Events with a `RecordTypeId` that you associated with Events that are appropriate for Community Users to see would be visible to them. That would be something you'd include in a custom profile for Community Users.

Comment: Hi, could you please extend more on your answer, I have the same issue as above. I have created a new record type in events, and I have assign the activities to this record type. I have assign all the profiles when I was creating them. I still can see activities that have this record type assigned

Comment: Why did you assign all the profiles to the new RecordTypeID if you didn't want it to be visible to all of them? Only assign the profiles you want it to be visible to.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the prompt response, because I want to be visible to all, including the Partner Community License. However with this I can only see the events assign o the particular user (within the community)

Comment: That sounds like an issue that's one related to ownership and sharing rules for the event.

Comment: well on sharing settings I have: activities: Controlled by Parent and I also have enable external sharing model. Any ideas will be super appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: I also notice,  in Sharing Settings, when i select the activity object I have the following message at the bottom of the page:
 Sharing Rules
You cannot create sharing rules for this item.

Comment: At this point, I must ask that you post a new question as this is no longer relevant to my answer posted above.